# How disable Downloading Components in Android Studio first running

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I extract Android Studio IDE 135.1740770,
Also these packages are installed for SDK:
Tools
- Android SDK Tools 24.1.2
- Android SDK platform-tools 22
- Android SDK Build-tools 22.0.1
Extras
- Android Support Repository 13
- Android Support Library 22.1
- Google Play services 23
- Google Repository 16
- Google USB Driver 11

But when I run Android Studio for the first time, although it asks for location of my sdk folder, but it wants to download older sdk build tools again:
- Android SDK Tools 22.1.2
- Android SDK platform-tools 21
- Sources for android 21
and after downloading all of them (about 500 MB) then removes them again!!! and use the newer sdk tools that I installed before :|
How can I run Android Studio for the first time without re-downloading these useless sdk packages?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

go to the installation directory of Android Studio. There you will find a folder named `bin`. Inside this folder there is a file named `idea.properties`. Open this file and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

What this will do is disable the check that Android Studio performs on first run and decides to download all that stuff.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer because it works.

Comment: how to do in macbook. Thanks you