# How to add android sdk to not setup(new) Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I installed Android Studio and when I try to start it, it automatically starts to download some packages.

I already have android sdk and I want my studio to use this one instead of downloading.

How can I do it?

Please, take into account that Android Studio is not set up yet.

Comment: its necessary packages so that download automatically ....

Comment: once downloaded completed after that you can change manual updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an SDK to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594611/how-do-you-add-an-sdk-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer downloading the `.zip` version rather than the `.exe` version. Go to the link http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-4-0 and download the `Plain .zip file` there based on the OS you are using. For window it is: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.4.0.10/android-studio-ide-141.2288178-windows.zip

Once that's done, extract the zip and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012311/4747587. This will ensure that when you first start `studio` downloading does not happen.

Start Studio. Go to  `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`. Give your SDK path here.